# I'm trying to write a number guessing game in python but my program isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7

The program is supposed to randomly generate a number between 1 and 10  (inclusive) and ask the user to guess the number. If they get it wrong, they can guess again until they get it right. If they guess right, the program is supposed to congratulate them.

This is what I have and it doesn't work. I enter a number between 1 and 10 and there is no congratulations. When I enter a negative number, nothing happens.

```
import random


number = random.randint(1,10)

print "The computer will generate a random number between 1 and 10. Try  to guess the number!"

guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))


while guess != number:
    if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
       print "Sorry, you are wrong."
       guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: ")) 
   elif guess <= 0 and guess >= 11: 
      print "That is not an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."
      guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))
   elif guess == number:
     print "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
```

Comment: How are you generating `number`?

Comment: First, everything in the while loop is dependent on the guess being wrong. Then inside it, if the first `if` condition matches (i.e. if `guess` is between 1 and 10), then the player is told they are wrong. That will block out the case where the guess was correct.

Comment: Move the congratulations outside the while loop and get rid of the last elif

Comment: `guess <= 0 and guess >= 11` can never be `True`. You need `guess <= 0 or guess >= 11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the congratulations message outside the loop.  You can then also only have one guess input in the loop.  The following should work:

```
while guess != number:
    if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
        print "Sorry, you are wrong."
    else:
        print "That is not an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."

    guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))

print "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
```

Comment: For the 3-guess version, you can add an outer loop that starts with `while True:` and at the bottom of the loop, ask if the user wants to play again.  If the answer is no, then execute a `break` statement to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in a if/elif chain, it evaluates them from top to bottom.
Move the last condition up.

```
if guess == number:
   ..
elif other conditions.
```

Also you need to change your while loop to allow it to enter in the first time. eg.

```
while True:
 guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))
 if guess == number:
   ..
```

then break whenever you have a condition to end the game.

Comment: It will never match that condition anyway, given the `while` condition.

Comment: That won't make any difference.  The loop body is only executed is `guess` is not equal to `number`.

Comment: Should i change it to "while guess >=1 and guess <= 10:" and start with this?

Comment: Well guess would need to be initialized if you're going to check against it like that.  But if you initialize it as, say 1, then sure, it will end if you type, say, 11.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you exit the while loop if the condition of guessing correctly is true. The way I suggest to fix this is to move the congratulations to outside the while loop

```
import random


number = random.randint(1,10)

print "The computer will generate a random number between 1 and 10.   Try  to guess the number!"

guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))


while guess != number:
    if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
       print "Sorry, you are wrong."
       guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: ")) 
    elif guess <= 0 and guess >= 11: 
       print "That is not an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."
       guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))

if guess == number:
 print "Congratulations! You guessed correctly!"
```