# Issues with my number guessing game in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to programming so please forgive the mess below...I was trying to write a number guessing game. The computer is supposed to randomly generate a number between 1 and 10 inclusively. The user is only allowed 3 tries to correctly guess the number. One the user either guesses correctly or runs out of tries, I am supposed to have the program ask the user if they want to play again and the game is supposed to restart. Below is what I've come up with. I think I am making this much more complicated than it needs to be...what am I doing wrong because it does not work?

```
import random


number = random.randint(1,10)


print "The computer will generate a random number between 1 and 10. Try to guess the number!"

guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))
attempts = 0


while guess != number and attempts < 4:
    if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
       print "Sorry, you are wrong."
    else:
       print "That is not an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."
       guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))
       attempts = attempts + 1
        if attempts > 4:
           print "You've guessed incorrectly and are out of tries..."
           playAgain = raw_input("Would you like to play again? ")
          if playAgain = "Yes" or playAgain == "y":
            import random
            number = random.randint(1,10)
            attempts = 0
            guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))
            while guess != number and attempts < 4:
                if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
                    print "Sorry, you are wrong."
                else:
                    print "That is not an interger between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."
                    guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))
                    attempts = attempts + 1
while guess == number:                        
    print "Congratulations, you guessed correctly!"
    playAgain = raw_input("Would you like to play again? ")
        if playAgain = "Yes" or playAgain == "y":
            import random
            number = random.randint(1,10)
            attempts = 0
            guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))
            while guess != number and attempts < 4:
                if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
                    print "Sorry, you are wrong."
                else:
                    print "That is not an interger between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."
                    guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))
                    attempts = attempts + 1
                    if attempts > 3:
                       print "You've guessed incorrectly and are out of tries..."
                       playAgain = raw_input("Would you like to play again? ")
                          if playAgain == "yes" or playAgain == "Yes":
                             import random
                             number = random.randint(1,10)
                             attempts = 0
                             guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number: "))
                             while guess != number and attempts < 4:
                                  if guess >= 1 and guess <= 10:
                                     print "Sorry, you are wrong."
                                  else:
                                       print "That is not an interger between 1 and 10 (inclusive)."
                                       guess = int(raw_input("Guess another number: "))
                                       attempts = attempts + 1
                                       if attempts > 3:
                                          print "You've guessed incorrectly and are out of tries..."
                                          playAgain = raw_input("Would you like to play again? ")
                                          if playAgain == "yes" or playAgain == "Yes":
                                             import random
                                             number = random.randint(1,10)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm hoping somebody will be able to tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: We don't have any idea what you're doing wrong because you haven't told us anything, all you've done is dropped a wall of code and expected us to debug it for you. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to include the desired behavior, including example inputs and outputs, the actual behavior, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. *"Somebody make this better for me"* is not an appropriate question here.

Comment: For starters, you import random a whole bunch of times and reset attempts to 0 everytime you respond with yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to write a number guessing game in python but my program isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586714/im-trying-to-write-a-number-guessing-game-in-python-but-my-program-isnt-workin)

Comment: @BrittLynn wondering if the answers helped you to resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

A little less advanced solution for someone who is a beginner:

```
import random

attempts = 0

number = random.randint(1,10)    

while attempts < 4:
    attempts += 1
    print number       #print number to help with testing
    guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number from 1 to 10: "))
    if guess == number:
        print "you guessed the number!", 
        again = raw_input("do you want to play again? y or n  ")      
        if again == "y":
            number = random.randint(1,10)
            attempts = 0    # gives 4 attempts to a new game
        else:
            print "good bye"                
            break    
    elif attempts == 4:
        print "The game is over!"
```

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution... You prompt to input a number twice for each replay and generate a new random number for each attempt.

Comment: @cricket_007 asking if the user wants to play again starts a new game so you want to generate a new random number, new game new number!

Comment: Sure, but you raw_input there and at the top of the while. Also the game is played with 3 attempts at guessing the same number.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for your help, I changed attempts to 0, I think now looks about perfect

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check how loops work, you cant really do things manually, check this code for an example of implementation with loops and functions:

```
import random

def guessGame():
    guessnum = random.randint(1,10)
    print "Try to guess the number between 1 and 10 in 3 ansers or less"
    i = 1
    while i < 4:
        try:
            num = int(raw_input("Attempt " + str(i) + ": "))
            if num == guessnum:
                return True
            else:
                i+=1
                print "Try again"
        except Exception as e:
            print "Please input a valid number"
            continue

def mainLoop():
    while True:
        guessGame()
        exitopt = raw_input("Good game, wanna try again? y - yes, n - no: ")
        if exitopt == "y":
            continue
        elif exitopt == "n":
            print "Bye!!!"
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainLoop()
```